# Let $(a,b), (c,d)$ be two vectors in $\mathbb R^2$. If $ad-bc=0$ prove that they are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $(a,b), (c,d)$ be two vectors in $\mathbb R^2$. If $ad-bc=0$ prove that they are linearly dependent

My attempt: I tried to do it by contradiction: Suppose that they are linearly independent that is:

$\alpha_1(a,b)+\alpha_2(c,d)=\vec0$ then $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$; solving the system:
$\begin{cases}
\alpha_1a+\alpha_2c=0 \\[2ex]
\alpha_1b+\alpha_2d=0
\end{cases}$

$$\alpha_1ba-\alpha_1ba+\alpha_2bc-\alpha_2da=0 \Rightarrow \alpha_2(bc-ad)=0$$ hence either $bc-ad=0$ or $bc-ad\neq0$ if it is the latter one then we have a contradiction

I would like you to tell me if this is correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $ad-bc=0$, then $ad=bc$, so $a\cdot(c,d)=(ac,ad)=(ac,bc)=c\cdot(a,b)$.  Therefore $$a(c,d) - c(a,b) = 0.$$

This proves linear dependence unless $a=c=0$.  But if $a=c=0$, then you have 
$$b(0,d) - d(0,b) =0.$$
This proves linear dependence unless also $b=d=0$.  If $a=b=c=d=0$, then $$5(a,b)+72(c,d)=0.$$

Answer (score 2):

If you know what are matrices and determinants, you can use them as well.

Say you have two (row) vectors $(a, b)$ and $(c, d)$ and put them in a matrix, one below the other, like this:

$$M := \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then $\det M = ad - bc$, which is zero if and only if $M$ is singular, which is true if and only if its rows (our original vectors) are linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems correct to me but the writing seems a little ambiguous.

You can improve the writing: Let $\alpha_1(a,b)+\alpha_2(c,d)=0$, without making your assumption about linear independence.

Proceed as you did. In the last step, $\alpha_2(bc-ad)=0$, use your given fact that $bc-ad=0$ to prove that $\alpha_2\neq 0$ which proves linear dependence.

Comment: thanks a lot! just one last thing: when I use the fact that $bc-ad=0$ then $\alpha_2=0$ or $\alpha_2\neq 0$, but I just want to have that $\alpha_2\neq 0$ so is it irrelevant that $\alpha_2=0$?

Comment: "prove that $\alpha_2\neq 0$"?  Do you mean, prove that $\alpha_2$ need not be $0$?

Comment: Your $\alpha_2$ can't be zero here! If you have $a\cdot b=0$ and $b\neq 0$ then $a$ has to be zero, isn't it? That's the case here.

Comment: Diya: That's not the case in what you wrote.  You have $a\cdot b=0$ and $b=0$, and want to conclude that $a\neq 0$, which doesn't follow.  But it does follow that $a$ need not be $0$.

Comment: Ah, I get the confusion now. In that case, I think it's best to go by the determinant approach. Do you know determinants OP?

Comment: Well just a little; how can I use determinants in this problem?

Comment: Diya, I think the original approach here is salvageable. All you need to show is that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ do not both need to be $0$.  Of course the equation holds when they are zero, but if $ad-bc=0$, you can also show it *can* hold when they're not both zero.

Answer (score 1):

We need to prove that $\alpha(a,b)+\beta(c,d)=(0,0)$ have solutions for scalars $\alpha, \beta$ different of zero.

Then, solving for $\alpha, \beta $ you will have $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\cdot \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Since a homogeneus system of equations have unique or infinite solutions, your unique option is to have infinite number of solutions and this occurs when $\text{rank}\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\right) < 2$ or equivalent $\det\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\right) = ad - bc = 0$.

So the solutions for $\alpha, \beta$ are infinite when $ad-bc=0$, that is, is linearly dependent.

You can generalize this for any eucliden vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$.